# Is there any reason to capture a return-value as an rvalue-reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I have a move-only struct `Foo`, and a function `Foo get();`

If I want to capture the return value of `get` in a mutable manner, I have two options:

- by value (`Foo`)
- by rvalue-reference (`Foo&&`)

When I capture by rvalue-reference I create an lvalue, much like capturing by value.

I'm struggling to see the point between the different options?

- Is there *any* difference between these two?

**Working example:**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::string s) : s(std::move(s)) {}
    Foo(Foo&& f)       : s(std::move(f.s)) {}

    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;

    std::string s;
};

Foo get()
{
    return Foo { "hello" };
}

int main()
{
    // capture return value as l-value
    Foo lv1 = get();

    // move into another lvalue
    Foo lv2 = std::move(lv1);
    std::cout << lv2.s << '\n';

    // capture return value as r-value reference
    Foo&& rv1 = get();

    // move into another lvalue
    Foo lv3 = std::move(rv1);
    std::cout << lv3.s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Foo lv1 = get();
> ```

This requires that `Foo` is copy/moveable.

> ```
> Foo&& rv1 = get();
> ```

This does not (at least, not as far as this line of code is concerned; the implementation of `get` may still require one).

Even though compilers are permitted to elide the copy of the return value into the variable, copy initialization of this form still requires the existence of an accessible copy or move constructor.

So if you want to impose as few limitations on the type `Foo` as possible, you can store a `&&` of the returned value.

Of course, C++17 changes this rule so that the first one doesn't need a copy/move constructor.

Comment: Why not using `const auto&` for object return types (or what's the difference)? As in this case there is no need for RVO or the need for a copy/move constructor, as the lifetime of the object is extended.

Comment: @DrumM: Maybe you want to modify the object that was returned.

Comment: True. Most of the time you don't want that. But in any case, if you don't want to change the object. What do you prefer?

Answer (score 4):

```
Foo&&
```

this creates a reference to a temporary value (or stores a rvalue reference assigned to it). If it stores a reference to a temporary value, its lifetime extends the value.

```
Foo
```

This stores a copy of the value, regardless of what was returned.

In C++11 and 14, if `Foo` cannot be moved, assigning `Foo make_foo()` to a variable of type `Foo` is illegal.  There is a move there, even if the move is elided (and the return value and the value in the outer scope have merged lifetimes).

In C++17, guaranteed elision means that no move constructor need exist.

```
Foo x = make_foo(); // Foo make_foo()
```

the above in C++17 guarantees that the return value of `make_foo()` is just named `x`.  In fact, a temporary *within* `make_foo` may also be `x`; the same object, with different names.  No move need occur.

There are a few other subtle differences.  `decltype(x)` will return the declared type of `x`; so `Foo` or `Foo&&` depending.

Another important difference is its use with `auto`.

```
auto&& x = some_function();
```

this creates a reference to anything.  If `some_function` returns a temporary, it binds an rvalue reference to it and extends its lifetime.  If it returns a reference, `x` matches the type of the reference.

```
auto x = some_function();
```

this creates a value, which may be copied from what `some_function` returns, or may be elided with the return value of `some_function` if it returns a temporary.

`auto&&` means, in a sense, "just make it work, and don't do extra work", and it could deduce to a `Foo&&`.  `auto` means "store a copy".

In the "almost always auto" style, these will be more common than an explicit `Foo` or `Foo&&`.

`auto&&` will never deduce to `Foo`, but can deduce to `Foo&&`.

The most common uses of `auto&&`, even outside of almost always auto, would be:

```
for(auto&& x : range)
```

where `x` becomes an efficient way to iterate over the range, where we don't care what type `range` has much.  Another common use is:

```
[](auto&& x){ /* some code */ }
```

lambdas are often used in contexts where the type is obvious and not worth typing again, like being passed to algorithms or the like.  By using `auto&&` for parameter types we make the code less verbose.

Comment: " If it stores a reference to a temporary value, its lifetime extends the value." - only if the return value is a prvalue.  A pitfall would be if the function returns an xvalue denoting a temporary, e.g. `Foo&& f = std::move( std::string{} );`

Comment: @m.m. yes, that is hard to word right without devolving into standardese